# Performing a left outer join on two MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have two SQL queries in a scheduling application to help check the availability of employees. I need to perform a left outer join but I can't seem to get the syntax quite right.

The first query gets a list of employees who are available at a given time and carry the right qualifications to perform the task to be scheduled.

```
    SELECT e.e_id FROM AppointmentTypes a1
    INNER JOIN EmployeeQualifications eq ON a1.type_id = eq.ea_id
    INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.e_id = eq.e_id
    INNER JOIN EmployeeAvaliable ea ON ea.e_id = e.e_id
    INNER JOIN EmployeeTimes et ON et.time_id = ea.time_id
    INNER JOIN AppointmentTimes a2
    INNER JOIN TypeTimes tt ON tt.time_id = a2.time_id AND tt.type_id = a1.type_id
    WHERE et.wednesday = '1'
    AND a1.type_id = '4'
    AND et.start <= '10:00:00' 
    AND et.end > '10:00:00'
```

The second query gets a list of employees who already have events scheduled at this time.

```
    SELECT e.e_id
    FROM AppointmentTypes atp 
    INNER JOIN Appointments a ON atp.type_id = a.type_id 
    INNER JOIN EmployeesAttending ea ON a.a_id = ea.a_id 
    INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.e_id = ea.e_id 
    WHERE date(a.start_time) = '2014-12-10'
    AND ADDTIME(time(a.start_time),'02:00:00') > '10:00:00'
    AND time(a.start_time) < '12:00:00'
```

Left outer joining these should give me a list of employees who are qualified, available, and don't already have an event scheduled at the time.

Answer (score 0):

No a left outer join will give you everything from the left plus the ones on the right that can be joined. Null where they cannot.

I think What you want to do is get everything in the first set that is not in the second set.

```
SELECT e.e_id FROM AppointmentTypes a1
INNER JOIN EmployeeQualifications eq ON a1.type_id = eq.ea_id
INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.e_id = eq.e_id
INNER JOIN EmployeeAvaliable ea ON ea.e_id = e.e_id
INNER JOIN EmployeeTimes et ON et.time_id = ea.time_id
INNER JOIN AppointmentTimes a2
INNER JOIN TypeTimes tt ON tt.time_id = a2.time_id AND tt.type_id = a1.type_id
WHERE et.wednesday = '1'
AND a1.type_id = '4'
AND et.start <= '10:00:00' 
AND et.end > '10:00:00'
AND e.e_id NOT IN (
    SELECT e.e_id
FROM AppointmentTypes atp 
INNER JOIN Appointments a ON atp.type_id = a.type_id 
INNER JOIN EmployeesAttending ea ON a.a_id = ea.a_id 
INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.e_id = ea.e_id 
WHERE date(a.start_time) = '2014-12-10'
AND ADDTIME(time(a.start_time),'02:00:00') > '10:00:00'
AND time(a.start_time) < '12:00:00'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.e_id 
FROM AppointmentTypes a1
INNER JOIN EmployeeQualifications eq ON a1.type_id = eq.ea_id
INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.e_id = eq.e_id
INNER JOIN EmployeeAvaliable ea ON ea.e_id = e.e_id
INNER JOIN EmployeeTimes et ON et.time_id = ea.time_id
INNER JOIN AppointmentTimes a2
INNER JOIN TypeTimes tt ON tt.time_id = a2.time_id AND tt.type_id = a1.type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e.e_id
                 FROM AppointmentTypes atp 
                 INNER JOIN Appointments a ON atp.type_id = a.type_id 
                 INNER JOIN EmployeesAttending ea ON a.a_id = ea.a_id 
                 INNER JOIN Employees e ON e.e_id = ea.e_id 
                 WHERE DATE(a.start_time) = '2014-12-10' AND 
                       ADDTIME(TIME(a.start_time),'02:00:00') > '10:00:00' AND 
                       TIME(a.start_time) < '12:00:00'
                ) AS A ON e.e_id = A.e.e_id  
WHERE et.wednesday = '1' AND a1.type_id = '4' AND 
      et.start <= '10:00:00' AND et.end > '10:00:00' AND
      A.e.e_id IS NULL;
```